# Quelle est la différence de sens entre compliquer et complexifier ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage

Quelle est la différence de sens entre les 2 verbes suivants : compliquer et complexifier ?

Par exemple pour ces phrases :

> Tu compliques les choses.
>
> Tu complexifies les choses.

J'ai beau regarder dans le dictionnaire, j'obtiens quasiment la même définition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Complexifier* est en général employé avec une connotation neutre ou positive. *Compliquer* a une connotation négative.

Si je **complexifie** une idée c'est que j'apporte des éléments **supplémentaires** pour **enrichir** la réflexion.
Si je **complique** une idée c'est que je dis les choses de façon **embrouillée** et que je pourrais dire **la même chose** en étant plus claire.

Je peux **complexifier** un système (mécanique par exemple) en introduisant des éléments/pièces **supplémentaires** dans le but de lui donner des fonctions qu'il n'a pas encore et que je juge utiles.
Par contre si je **complique** un système c'est que je lui ajoute des éléments qui ne sont pas nécessaires pour faire ce qu'il a à faire.

En gros complexifier c'est ajouter quelque chose dans un but d'amélioration et compliquer c'est apporter trop d'éléments à quelque chose qui pourrait être conçu de façon plus simple pour un même résultat.

Comment: Hé, coiffé au poteau par cette bonne réponse ! Certains sites web s'amusent à... compliquer les choses, voir la [définition de `complexifier` chez Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/complexifier/17698)...

Comment: @FredP Merci pour ce lien fort amusant. Je suis d'accord avec toi qu'à force vouloir faire simple certains dictionnaires compliquent les choses à loisir !

Comment: C'est marrant car il m'arrive d'utiliser le terme _complexifier_ pour signifier à l'interlocuteur qu'il rend plus complexe les choses mais de manière négative.

Comment: @Zistoloen Tu ne dois pas être le seul (et voir le lien donné pas FredP) mais c'est à mon avis un abus de langage qui peut prêter à confusion.  L'usage de « complexe » pour signifier « compliqué » (c'est à dire avec connotation négative) est qualifié de **courant et abusif** par *Le Petit Robert* qui défini « complexifier » par « rendre  complexe » et « complexe » par « qui contient plusieurs éléments différents ».  sans être prescriptiviste,  c'est parfois pratique d'utiliser les mots avec un sens reconnu pour éviter les confusions.

Comment: Il me semble aussi qu'il est juste bon d'ajouter que _complexifier_ est beaucoup plus rarement utilisé que _compliquer_...

Comment: A good note on the nuance that also explains why the movie title ["It's Complicated"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It's_Complicated_(film)) was not translated by the rather more negative (and less idiomatic) "C'est compliqué", which would have been "literal" enough, but by ["Pas si simple"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pas_si_simple_(film)) :)

Answer (score 3):

D'après mon expérience, à l'usage, *complexifier* se veut plus mathématique (au sens de "rendre complexe", rendre moins simple, moins direct à analyser). *Compliquer* se veut plus courant, oral et signifie pour moi "rendre confus".
Au quotidien, à moins d'être en situation effectivement mathématique ou purement scientifique, je ne suis pas certain de voir ce qui amènerait l'usage de *complexifier*.

Si on en revient à l'étymologie des adjectifs,

- *complexe* tiré du latin  **complecti** évoque le fait de comprendre plusieurs parties,
- *compliqué* tiré du latin **complicatus** évoque le fait d'être confus car constitué de plusieurs parties enroulées, repliées les unes sur les autres.

(sources : *etymonline* et *CNTRL.FR*)

Cela semble donc en effet proche.

Answer (score 3):

Dans la pratique, *compliqué* et *complexe* sont souvent utilisés comme synonymes, *complexe* est vu comme une forme plus savante de *compliqué* sans que le sens soit réellement différent.

Certains cependant opposent parfois *complexe* et *compliqué*, et alors *compliqué* décrit quelque chose de plus intrinsèque que *complexe*, qui décrit plutôt une propriété émergente dans un système composé de multiples choses qui peuvent être simples isolées et dont les rapports individuels peuvent être tout aussi simples.

Les verbes *compliquer* et *complexifier* sont aussi utilisés comme synonymes et à nouveau *complexifier* est alors vu comme une forme plus savante de *compliquer* sans que le sens soit réellement différent.

Quand on les oppose, *complexifier* tend à décrire l'ajout de choses pertinentes mais qui rendent l'ensemble plus difficile à saisir, *compliquer* tend plutôt à décrire une absence de structure (volontaire ou non) dans l'explication ou l'intervention de considérations non pertinentes.

Answer (score 1):

Les termes *complexe* et *compliqué* sont communément confondus dans leur sens, cependant, une nuance existe et qui mérite d'être soulignée: Si **complexe** est souvent utilisé pour signifier la difficulté intrinsèque de ce qui est qualifié de tel (un problème, une situation, une méthode...), **compliqué** dénote plutôt, plus, la confusion ou la difficulté générée (Ainsi, je ne comprends plus rien de ce problème, de cette situation, devenu(e) compliqué(e)...)